# tex4ht/make4ht: configure the section title so it is jekyll toc compatable

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht

Currently a section title `\section{Connection}`
will create HTML

```
<h3 class='sectionHead'><span class='titlemark'>1   </span> <a id='x1-10001'></a>Connection</h3>
```

I want it to be a simple format so that the entry has no extra junk with `jekyll-toc`, so ideally:

```
\section{Connection}
\section{Parallel Transport}
```

will become

```
<h3 class='sectionHead' id='section-1'>1 Connection</h3>
<h3 class='sectionHead' id='section-2'>2 Parallel Transport</h3>
```

I have tried several configurations

```
\Configure{section} 
   {}{} 
   {\HCode{<h2 id="section-">}\Title\space}    {\HCode{</h2>}} 
\ConfigureMark{section}{\thesection}
```

but have no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this configuration:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{section} 
   {}{} 
   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<h2 id="section-\thesection">}\TitleMark\space}    {\HCode{</h2>}} 
\ConfigureMark{section}{\thesection}
\makeatletter
\Configure{toTocLink}{\@gobbletwo}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

You need to use `\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP` to close the current paragraph, otherwise your section will be included in one. You can use `\thesection` to construct the `id`. There will be always a link that is a destination to and from TOC, even if you don't use one. You can remove it using `\Configure{toTocLink}{\@gobbletwo}{}`.

This is the resulting HTML code:

```
---
meta:
- charset: 'utf-8'
- content: 'TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)'
  name: 'generator'
- content: 'width=device-width,initial-scale=1'
  name: 'viewport'
- content: '2022-12-03-sample.tex'
  name: 'src'
styles:
- '2022-12-03-sample.css'
time: 1670080935
title: ''
---

   <h2 id='section-1'>1 Connection</h2>
<!--   l. 5   --><p class='noindent'>
</p>
   <h2 id='section-2'>2 Parallel Transport</h2>
```

Comment: The answer works almost perfect except that `jekyll-toc` requires id to be in *double quotation marks* (`id="section-1"`) to work. Is there any go arounds?

Comment: No, quotes are handled by LuaXML, and it always converts them to single quotes. isn't it possible for Jekyll-toc to support single quotes? It is perfectly fine html.